# Why does chrome keep sending me errors about an if statement (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

There is an "if" in line 7 but why does it errors me?
And by the way: I'm new to all this php, mysql...
and I made a sign up form, that connect's to mysql data base, I learned it from some kind of tutorial online... As I think you all knows I'm working on xampp and I entered to the "localhost" after I "sign up" to my form it didn't did **nothing** I looked all over my code and I didn't saw any prblem, should I post the code?
here's the code:

```
<?php
$db_host="#$%$%#$#";
$db_username="####";
$db_pass="*#*#*#*#";
$db_name="#####_****";
$link = mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass");
if (!$link){
    die ("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
}
$db_selected= mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);
if (!$db_selected){
    die ("can't use".$db_name. ": ". mysql_error());
}
$UserName=$_POST['UserName'];
$Password=$_POST['Password'];
$Email=$_POST['Email'];
$Terms_Of_Use=$_POST['Check_Box'];
?>
<script>
if (Checkbox.checked){
<?php
$Terms_Of_Use="y";
?>
}else{
<?php
echo("To continue please check the 'terms of use' box!");
die;
?>
}
</script>
<?php
$sqlu="INSERT INTO Members (UserName) VALUES ('UserName')";
$sqlp="INSERT INTO Members (Password) VALUES ('Password')";
$sqle="INSERT INTO Members (Email) VALUES ('Email')";
$sqlt="INSERT INTO Members (Terms_Of_Use) VALUES ('Terms_Of_Use')";
if(!mysql_query($sqlu)){
die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
}
if(!mysql_query($sqlp)){
die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
}
if(!mysql_query($sqle)){
die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
}
if(!mysql_query($sqlt)){
die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
}
mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Just think logically. How could we tell you what the problem is without seeing your code? The best we could do is guessing. And next time, instead of an image, just paste the error into your question, please.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semicolon after your `mysql_connect()`.

Comment: OK thanks, but know I have another 2 errors:
Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysql.php on line 6

Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysql.php on line 6